# Weird ScrollView behaviour when its inside of moving View. SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, scrollview

I have container view which can be draged around and it has scrollview inside with bunch of buttons. When i drag the container view scrollViews starts to jump up and down weirdly, also buttons' hitboxes start be way off from actual buttons. (You can see my gif)
But when I touch scrollview everything gets back to normal.
[image: Demo weird scrollview]

This code is purely for testing

That's the main view

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State var width : CGFloat = 300
    @State var height : CGFloat = 300
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            SecondView(width: width, height: height){
                ScrollView{
                    VStack{
                        ForEach(0...10, id : \.self){ i in
                            
                            TestButton(number: i)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Slider(value: $width, in: 100...500)
            Slider(value: $height, in: 100...500)
        }
    }
}
```

That's the dragable view

```
    struct SecondView<Content : View> : View {
    var width : CGFloat
    var height : CGFloat
    var content : () -> Content
    @GestureState private var dragState = DragState.inactive
    @State var position : CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    var body : some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture().updating($dragState){ drag, state, transition in
            state = .dragging(translation: drag.translation)
            
        }.onEnded({drag in
            self.position.height+=drag.translation.height
            self.position.width+=drag.translation.width
        })
        return VStack{
            Handle()
            
            content().padding()
            
        }.frame(width: width, height: height).background(Color.yellow).cornerRadius(10)
            .offset(x: self.position.width + dragState.translation.width, y: self.position.height + dragState.translation.height)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
        
    }
    
    enum DragState {
        case inactive
        case dragging(translation : CGSize)
        
        
        var translation : CGSize {
            switch self {
            case .inactive:
                return .zero
            case .dragging(let translation):
                return translation
            }
        }
        
        var isDragging : Bool {
            switch self {
            case .inactive:
                return false
            case .dragging:
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it is a bug or it's me doing something wrong, but looks like bug
Thanks in advance for answers and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.offset` modifier does not change views layout, so moved view really remains on the same place and hit areas remains on same place, it just drawn in different location.

Thus `.offset` does not fit for your goal, instead refactor to use `.position`, which really changes view hierarchy (but affects entire layout as well, so your floating pane should be placed in separated `ZStack` to avoid others).